cannot get imx219 camera working on raspberrypi os bookworm running in pi 4b
When running
libcamera-still list-cameras

, the camera is listed. However
libcamera-hello 

gives an error 'failed to acquire camera'.
So does
libcamera-still -o test.jpg. 

I have made some mods to /boot/firmware/config.txt.  These are:
(1) comment out camera_auto_detect = 1.  Before i did this, libcamera-still list-cameras did not show the camera at all.
(2) I added line dtoverlay=imx219  This did nothing.
Subsequently I decided that camera_autodetect should be set to 0 rather than commenting it out. Also I note that libcamera is deprecated in 'bookworm' so I have tried the rpicam commands instead. rpicam-hello gives an error "V4L2 device unable to set controls or device busy". So I have not got any further.
Here is the full output from rpicam-hello:
[0:20:16.876868471] [5062] INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:316 libcamera v0.3.1+50-69a894c4
[0:20:16.894476720] [5078] ERROR V4L2 v4l2_device.cpp:353 'imx219 10-0010': Unable to set controls: Device or resource busy
[0:20:16.920461311] [5078] WARN RPiSdn sdn.cpp:40 Using legacy SDN tuning - please consider moving SDN inside rpi.denoise
[0:20:16.922498680] [5078] WARN RPI vc4.cpp:393 Mismatch between Unicam and CamHelper for embedded data usage!
[0:20:16.923189877] [5078] INFO RPI vc4.cpp:447 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10 to Unicam device /dev/media0 and ISP device /dev/media2
[0:20:16.923285116] [5078] INFO RPI pipeline_base.cpp:1125 Using configuration file '/usr/share/libcamera/pipeline/rpi/vc4/rpi_apps.yaml'
Preview window unavailable
[0:20:16.924242255] [5062] INFO Camera camera.cpp:998 Pipeline handler in use by another process
ERROR: *** failed to acquire camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx219@10 ***

I have now also tried taking out the dtoverlay=imx219 and setting the camera_auto_detect=1. rpicam-still --list-cameras continues to list the camera as detected.
This still leaves me in the same position with the same result from rpicam-hello.

please update the question ... comments are not for adding info
